# Language doesn't set to default Android Studio

Tags: java, android, locale

I have made an app, and following android developer instructions, i have added spaish as locale language so that Android automatically changes to spanish when the phone is set to spanish.

It works just fine when phone is set on spanish or english, however in any other language it wont change to the default language (english). If i had spanish on the phone, and change it to a different language, it will stay in spanish instead of changing to default english.

[Values folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlX20.png)

My manifest is almost the same as created by default:

[Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1H1t.png)

All activities except main have the exact same parameters as the one shown in the picture in Manifest.

[The project gradle looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXg0z.png)

This is the only part of the code where i call Locale class, to save the current language in a database to use for other things.

```
        if(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("es")){
            //setLocale("es");
            try {
                helper=new SQLHelperGeneral(this);
                helper.openDB();
                helper.updateLanguage("es");
                helper.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            try {
                helper=new SQLHelperGeneral(this);
                helper.openDB();
                helper.updateLanguage("en");
                helper.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I cant find the reason why my app only properly sets language for english and spanish only, and stays the same as before when language isnt one of those two.

Any ideas of what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had spent some time looking for an answer and some of the solutions sugested to watch otu for defaultConfig on Manifest, however the value that was seting the app to only detect english and spanish was resConfig in build gradle of the project.

If you attempt to change the language programatically, be carefu not to set said setting or it will not detect any other languages automatically.